# [Help]Pubkey error and many others!

Tags: apt, updates, gnupg

```
root@1:~# sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 67ECE5605BCF1346
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.VPRdHmtKUT/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 67ECE5605BCF1346
gpg: failed to start the dirmngr '/usr/bin/dirmngr': No such file or directory
gpg: connecting dirmngr at '/run/user/0/gnupg/d.ta6norsysbogeqchj9rj4s65/S.dirmngr' failed: No such file or directory
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No dirmngr
```

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/bin/dirmngr` is part of the `dirmngr` package. Install `dirmngr` via `sudo apt-get install dirmngr`.

Here is how I found out:

```
w3@aardvark:~(0)$ ll /usr/bin/dirmngr
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 368840 Apr  8  2016 /usr/bin/dirmngr
w3@aardvark:~(0)$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/dirmngr
dirmngr: /usr/bin/dirmngr
w3@aardvark:~(0)$ apt-cache search dirmngr
dirmngr - server for managing certificate revocation lists
```